# Thread IIS wont start C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, request, threadpool

Before I go into this question, I d like to say that, I have read the threading modeling for IIS 7, 7, 7.5 so I know how threads are handled.

My application starts a thread when a request comes in.

We can assume the threads as cron jobs.

1. GET request comes in, Lets say /Handle
2. in the scope of /Handle I start a thread from that action , THREAD A
3. I am not long polling the GET request, so it returns back to the
   user right away. So thread handling the GET is returned to the POOL
4. Then I wait until the thread A completes to do anything else.
5. So No threads are running as far as I know. Both the thread that was
   handling the GET and THREAD A has exited.

I make the same request a few times SEQUANTIALLY. I always wait for both threads to exit. 
After a while `Thread.Start()1 function blocks.

Questions :
I know that the threads are returning and I am not leaking any ghost threads. 
Why does IIS not allowing me to start new threads after a like 4-5 requests. ?

What is the right way to create application thread for the user application. 
If I said `Thread t= new Thread()`, does this allocate a thread from the pool that handled the GETS or CLR?
I am using IIS7.

I know that I exit each thread, I call a JOIN on THREAD A , and it never blocks, and at this point I am not worried about scalability so I always have  ONE user hitting the server sequentially.

Comment: As I understood it, creating threads directly using `new Thread()` creates a direct thread and doesn't touch the `ThreadPool`? And why are you waiting for the thread?

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the Thread?  Are you taking a thread from the Thread Pool?

Comment: "4.THen I wait until the thread A" - which thread waits for the thread, if the thread processing the request has already been returned to the pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer your question **"What is the right way to create application thread for the user application?"** (i.e. ASP.NET application) - You have many options:

- run on the ASP.NET thread, without any threading - ASP.NET will still handle more then one request
- use async calls (see [async operations](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/working-with-asynchronous-operations-in-asp.net-4.5-web-forms.htm)) for long running operations
- use [CLR ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- send a message to some other server (e.g. using WCF services), so the long running processing takes place outside the Web server.

You mentioned reading about threading in ASP.NET, but in ["MSDN: Performing Asynchronous Work, or Tasks, in ASP.NET Applications"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx) there's a relatively short description of how threading in ASP.NET works. At the end of the post, there's a question: 
**"Q4: Should I create my own threads (new Thread)?"** and the answer for that question is **"A4)  Please don’t (create new Threads).  Or to put it a different way, no!!! (...) ".**

And to answer your question: "**Why does IIS not allowing me to start new threads after a like 4-5 requests"?**
That's really a strange behaviour, maybe IIS knows that your are doing it wrong ;)

Comment: OK thanks. I have to use async, My ASP.NET thread has to return back to the user right away so we wont block the user. I also can not run it on a separate server as I use Pinvoke. The thread I created calls stuff in C, it post backs results.

Thanks there is the same concept in AppEngine. It is my first time in MS world.

Comment: So I forgot to say that I am using MVC . Therefor I need to use AsyncController. I dont think I made my self clear with what I need.
I do not need to return anything back to the user/client. I just want to run a back ground thread. AsyncTask/Controllers are implemented for long running threads which the  user eventually need to see some sort of a result back on the browser. All I need is to be able to run background threads? And not wait for them to finish.